# user-defined command instead of curl for REST api

Tags: python, rest

I have rest api like this

`@route("/api/v1/device/", methods=["GET", "POST"])`

Instead of using a `CURL` commands, can I use my user-defined commands for this route?

Eg. #show devices

I know I can do it using a python-wrapper around this api.Is there any other way or a better way to do this

Comment: Any REST client, like Postman for example?

Comment: Precise the framework you are coding with.

Comment: @KlausD. I want to use CLI.

Comment: @Cyrbil. I'm using rest api of Ryu controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryu is using WSGI so you will be able to query your route from your code using any WSGI client:

Example with werkzeug:

```
from werkzeug.test import Client
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response

client = Client(current_app, response_wrapper=Response)
res = client.open(
    method='GET',
    path='/api/v1/device/'
)
```

Note: Ryu seems to use webob so you may want to use it (i don't know if it provide non http client)...

Best case is to separate your controller code (that parse Request and return data) from your service code (that do the action and return result). So your service is callable from anywhere.